# MySQL LIKE on Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am writing a query where I am trying to pull out values based on a portion of a subquery and can't seem to work out how to get the needed values.

The table has only a half-dozen entries containing author names but in some instances, there is more than one author in the field and I need to get their separate individual biographies. Right now this gives no errors but it is pulling up only the single entry that contains both author names rather than the two that contain the actual biographies. I need only the two single-name entries, not the one containing both but it's giving the opposite.

AuthorName has something like this:

```
Joe Blow
Jane Doe
Jow Blow and Jane Doe
```

and here is the query

```
SELECT a.`ID` AS AuthorID, `AuthorName`, `AuthorPhoto`, `AuthorBio`, `Email`,
FROM authorbiographies a 
WHERE `AuthorName` LIKE CONCAT('%',(
SELECT `AuthorName` )
FROM authorbiographies WHERE `AuthorName` LIKE '% and %),'%'
) 
AND `ID` <> 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by joining a derived tables of all `authorname`s that don't include `and` with a derived table of all `authorname`s that do include `and`, as long as the first `authorname` is part of the second:

```
SELECT a1.id, a1.authorname, a1.authorbio
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM authorbiographies
      WHERE authorname NOT LIKE '% and %'
      ) a1
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM authorbiographies
      WHERE authorname like '% and %'
      ) a2 on a2.authorname LIKE concat('%', a1.authorname, '%')
```

Output (for your sample)

```
id  authorname  authorbio
1   Joe Blow    has lived a long time
2   Jane Doe    wrote several books
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6256c0/3)

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! Once I saw it working I realized that it is not necessary to use `LIKE '% and %'` and `NOT LIKE '% and %'` so I replaced those with `ID = $AuthorID` and `ID <> $AuthorID` which is a value being fed to the page. That way, if there are other dual authorships, it will pull up the proper match.

Comment: @DonP Good to hear. I'm glad you were able to modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM authorbiographies ab
WHERE ab.authorname NOT LIKE '% and %';
```

You seem to just want to pick out the rows that do not have `' and '` in them.

Comment: Why would you use `ab.*` instead of just `*` ?

Comment: @Austin . . . I qualify column references.